# Can't render videos loaded through OpenCV in PyQt4 gui on another computer through a python standalone executable. giving no errors does nothing

Tags: python, opencv, video, pyqt, py2exe

Here is the py2exe setup script:

```
 from setuptools import setup
 import py2exe
 from glob import glob
 import numpy
 import sys
 import cv2

SETUP_DICT = {
'windows': [{
    'script': 'C:\\Users\\Codemen1\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\video.py',
}],

'zipfile': 'lib/library.zip',

'data_files': (
    ('', glob(r'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcp100.dll')),
    ('', glob(r'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcr100.dll')),
),

'options': {
    'py2exe': {
        'bundle_files': 3,
        #'bundle_files': 1, 
        #'packages': 'cv2',
        'includes': ['sip', 'PyQt4.QtCore','numpy','sys','cv2'],

    },
  }
}

setup(**SETUP_DICT)
```

This setup.py script perfectly works on images & other functionalities if i make them executable.

Here is my pyqt code where i am displaying the video

```
 class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Control panel"))
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("Control panel", "Control panel", None))
    #MainWindow.resize(1407, 722)
    MainWindow.setFixedSize(800, 722)

    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))

    self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 160, 661))
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayoutWidget"))
    self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.verticalLayout.setMargin(0)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))               

    self.videoFrame = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.videoFrame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 40, 591, 611))
    self.videoFrame.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.videoFrame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("videoFrame"))

    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.videoFrame = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.videoFrame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 40, 591, 611))
    self.videoFrame.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.videoFrame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("videoFrame"))

    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class Video():
def __init__(self,capture):
         self.capture = capture
         self.currentFrame=np.array([])

def captureNextFrame1(self):
    """                           
    capture frame and reverse RBG BGR and return opencv image                                      
    """
    ret, readFrame=self.capture.read()
    if(ret==True):
            self.currentFrame=cv2.cvtColor(readFrame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


def convertFrame(self):
    """     converts frame to format suitable for QtGui            """
    try:
        height,width=self.currentFrame.shape[:2]
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        img=QtGui.QImage(self.currentFrame.data,width,height,bytesPerLine,QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        img=QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        self.previousFrame = self.currentFrame
        return img
    except:
        return None


  class Gui(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.video1 =  Video(cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Users\Public\\OpenCVproject\\IMG_1491.mov"))
        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.play)
        self._timer.start(27)
        self.update()

   def play(self):
        try:
          self.video1.captureNextFrame1()      
          self.ui.videoFrame.setPixmap(self.video1.convertFrame())
          self.ui.videoFrame.setScaledContents(True)


        except TypeError:
          print "No frame"

def main():        
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Gui()
  ex.show()    
  sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Nothing wrong with the code so far. Works perfectly. But if i make this a standalone exe file the video not rendering on other computer. Perfectly showing on mine.

Comment: Can you add more details on what you are trying to do? Provide the code and some background info... This is very vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. py2exe couldn't fetch all the ffmpeg,highgui & other dll & pyd files. So have to manually import all those file to my standable executable files & it solved the problem. Thank you.